# What are the proximity bonuses for adjacent buildings and when do they apply?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

The game makes it clear that labs and workshops get a bonus when built next to buildings of the same type. I've also seen it written online that Satellite Uplinks get a bonus but I can't see anywhere what it is.

What are all the buildings that get bonuses, and what are those bonuses? Supplemental question: Does "adjacent" mean horizontal or also vertical adjacency?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adjacency is horizontal *and* vertical.  Each "pair" of facilities counts as one adjacency bonus.  Generally you can count the plusses to determine the specific level of benefits you are receiving.

The types and adjacency bonuses are as follows:

1. Laboratory: 10% research speed bonus for each adjacency bonus.
2. Workshop: 7% refund on resources used to build items (that's gear, facilities, and vehiciles) for each adjacency bonus.
3. Satellite Uplink/nexus: +1 capacity for each adjacency bonus.
4. Power, Elerium, Thermal Generators: +2 power for each adjacency bonus.

Note that if you go into the Build Facilities screen, you can see this in the description text (of the currently highlighted facility), but sometimes you have to sit there and wait for it to start scrolling.

Comment: That last nugget is very interesting --- sometimes you have to sit and wait for it to start scrolling.

Comment: Unfortunately the UI design is such that only a part of the text is showing.

Comment: Is the adjacency bonus for each facility? ie two labs next to each other would be +10 for the first and +10 for the second or is it just +10 for having one link between them? Does it tell you anywhere what your current adjacency bonuses are?

Comment: @Chris You can tell this by looking at your satellites or power.  I don't think it's possible to know for Workshops/Labs.  I'll double check my base when I get home and make note of what I find.

Comment: @Chris: I'm fairly sure it's +10 for the link, not +10 for each lab. This is definitely true for satellite uplinks. I built mine out as a square, the top two being uplinks and the bottom two being nexuses (nexi?). The first one was good for two satellites, the second for three (2 + 1 bonus) the first nexus for five (4 + 1 bonus) and the second nexus for six (4 + 1 + 1).

Comment: I can't figure out why building adjacent workshops show that green `+` icon when having them adjacent don't seem to do anything.

Comment: @jprete: I tried looking at satellites but it gets confusing because the bonuses on the two different types are actually different (one is +1 satellite for two linked, one is +1 for each linked) and I dont' know if it measures those halves separately or what. You're right about power though which should be very straightforward. :)

Comment: @Chris pretty sure that's wrong. jprete and I share the same experience: building 2 uplinks + 2 nexuses in a square equals 16 satellites (2*2 + 2*4 + 4 adjacencies).

Comment: @kotekzot: I'm still confused as to how it works it out but am more than happy to accept your results. At some point I'll get a big stack of cash and play around a bit to understand it better. :)

Comment: @Chris every shared side between building of the same type = 1 adjacency bonus. In case of satellite facilities that is + 1 sat capacity, in case of labs it is +10% research speed and in case of workshops it is 7% rebate on certain projects.

Comment: But in the case of the basic satellite facility it is +1 for every two adjacent. So assuming that you take the better of the two bonuses for any single link with a two up two down you have three bonuses involving the better building and one with the lesser so I'd expect the lesser not to give anything (because there is only one lesser link and it requires two for an extra satellite) and the others to give three each meaning 15 satellites and not 16 as you are observing. Of course if the better ones were diagonal then I could see you getting +1 from all four links by the "best bonus" logic.

Comment: @Chris: It's conceivable that the bonus could work differently for each building type, or have other weird mechanisms, but why would they do that? The phrasing in the text, and the lack of good documentation for the mechanics in the game, are almost certainly the sources of the problem. This is an excellent game, but it needed a really good polish.

Comment: @jprete: Yeah, on playing last night I realised that the phrasing of the two satellite buildings could quite easily mean the same thing so I think you are right that the problem is just in the ambiguity of the phrasing. It certainly makes sense for the bonuses to be the same for the two buildings. :)

Comment: @peacedog I'm fairly certain that there's no difference between Satellite Uplinks and Satellite Nexuses with regard to the size of the adjacency bonus, and no difference between the way bonuses work for them and the way bonuses work for other facilities. I did a pretty thorough evaluation of the relative benefits of the two previously in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90460/how-is-the-number-of-engineers-required-to-build-facilities-calculated/92561#92561).

Comment: Well, I could have sworn it worked differently at launch.  It's actually pretty terribly worded in game.

Comment: @peacedog I think it's poorly worded in game because it's awkward talking about adjacency bonuses...since you get one for each distinct pair of adj. facilities, you might write that you get "one bonus for each two adjacent" (i.e. looking from a bird's eye view at two facilities that share one adjacency), or write that you get "one bonus for each adjacent" (picturing yourself in one facility, and saying "I get one bonus from that adjacent facility next door, and one from the facility on the floor above". Both mean the same thing. One + = one satellite uplink, one + = 10% faster research, etc.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock it's poorly worded in game because it's poorly worded, and for no other reason, and the radically different descriptions of the nexus and uplink show this.

Answer (score 3):

The adjacency bonus applies to all adjacent types next to each other. It also applies vertically. So, if you have four workshops in a 2x2 configuration then you will get four "adjacent" bonuses or a 28 percent return. Note that for workshops you get the rebate at the end of the job. I am putting in a 2 by 6 workstation complex that will yield a 49% rebate.

Also, for up-links if you want full satellite coverage, you'll need a capacity of 18. That will be three nexus stations all touching in one way or another.

It is worth while building the efficient power stations and then moving the pre-built facilities to more efficient configurations. It takes a while and you won't be able to do it all at once. But look at where your best steam row (or column, don't forget that you can plan this strategy in a vertical configuration too) is and plan for that to be your generator row/column/box. You may have to build some facilities in temporary locations in order to maintain full power but with some planning you can minimize this. Also don't forget that it takes a while to excavate so, do this when you can even if you're not planning to build right a way. I have found that keeping two spaces open for future development is a good practice. At least this was possible at "Normal" difficulty. One may find resources too limited to do this on higher difficulties.

My top two rows are all the specialty facilities as there will only be one of each of these. Also, don't move your Officer training school as you will lose your OTS upgrades and *you'll have to repurchase these after you've rebuilt your OTS.* -- This last bit is not correct. The upgrades come back when you rebuild your OTS.

Comment: The last paragraph is incorrect, the bonuses return as soon as you rebuild the school at no extra cost.

Answer (score 2):

On the PC version I get a green plus symbol between my 2 power plants and uplinks showing the adjancency bonus.
I assume the same symbol will appear when my 2nd adjacent lab and workshop complete.