# How do adjacency bonuses for base facilities really work?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the proximity bonuses for adjacent buildings and when do they apply?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87449/what-are-the-proximity-bonuses-for-adjacent-buildings-and-when-do-they-apply)

I'm a bit confused as to how exactly adjacency bonuses work for the base.

If I place say 4 satellite uplinks in a row like this:
X X X X

will that net me the same bonus as placing them in a square like this?

X X
X X

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case you show, the second arrangement will grant you a greater bonus than the first. With links represented by lines, in the first arrangement:

```
X-X-X-X
```

There are three links.
In the second arrangement:

```
X-X
| |
X-X
```

There are four links.

For every two adjacent facilities, you will get the adjacency bonus, and a building can be in multiple adjacency pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Placing them in a square will net you one greater number of bonuses (whatever the bonuses are).  Placing them in a line gives you three bonuses, as you have three adjacent links.  Placing them in a square gives you four bonuses, as you have four adjacent links.